# Oracle text scheduling sync on single index

Tags: oracle, text, oracle-text

I need to sync an oracle text index. But job fails to create:

```
declare
    v_job_id number(19,0);
begin
dbms_job.submit(
    JOB        => v_job_id,
    WHAT        => 'alter index NAME_IDX rebuild parameters (''sync'');',
    NEXT_DATE => SYSDATE + (1/24),
    INTERVAL    => 'SYSDATE + (1/24) + 7'
    );
end;
/
```

Or to run:

```
declare
    v_job_id number(19,0);
begin
dbms_job.submit(
    JOB        => v_job_id,
    WHAT        => 'CTX_DDL(''NAME_IDX'');',
    NEXT_DATE => SYSDATE + (1/24),
    INTERVAL    => 'SYSDATE + (1/24) + 7'
    );
end;
/
```

But if I run any of those works:

```
alter index NAME_IDX rebuild parameters ('sync');
call CTX_DDL('NAME_IDX');
```

Any idea of the correct syntax?

Thank you.

PD: Ive been searching, but the only answer I found doesnt fit my requirements. I also apologize for my english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run an anonymous block, CALL is not in PL/SQL, ALTER INDEX is DDL, and you need to specify which procedure in CTX_DDL you want to run:

```
WHAT => 'BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''alter index NAME_IDX rebuild parameters (''''sync'''')''; CTX_DDL.sync_index(''NAME_IDX''); END',
```

However, personally I prefer to encapsulate it in a procedure (or, even better, a package) and call the procedure from the job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rebuild_name_idx IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter index NAME_IDX rebuild parameters (''sync'')';
    CTX_DDL.sync_index('NAME_IDX');
END;
/

declare
    v_job_id number(19,0);
begin
  dbms_job.submit(
    JOB       => v_job_id,
    WHAT      => 'rebuild_name_idx;',
    NEXT_DATE => SYSDATE + (1/24),
    INTERVAL  => 'SYSDATE + (1/24) + 7'
    );
end;
/
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you don't actually need to rebuild the index - you only need to call `CTX_DDL.sync_index` to refresh it from any DML on the table.

Comment: Thank you. This is what worked for me:  WHAT      => 'BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''alter index NAME_IDX rebuild parameters (''''sync'''')''; END;',

Comment: Another question, and to CTX_DDL.OPTIMIZE_INDEX('INDEX_NAME', 'FULL', 45); for 45 mins. What whould the WHAT be?  Thakn you!

Comment: `what => 'CTX_DDL.OPTIMIZE_INDEX(''INDEX_NAME'', ''FULL'', 45);'`

Comment: my bad, it was a permission issue. Sorry.